# Question about devices, related to mathematics

Tags: support, allowed-questions

Well, I was searching for Math display and support in Amazon Kindle, surprisingly, I came across couple of questions about devices in MSE,

- [Kindle paperwhite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263889/kindle-paperwhite?rq=1)
- [A digital notebook for Mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118856/a-digital-notebook-for-mathematics/205789#205789)

The first one asks just what I want, but I fear the technology has taken slightly giant leap since 2012, when that question was asked.

In light of that, I have couple of questions:

1. Is it ok to ask about devices and math in MSE? Like, will Amazon Kindle (Paperwhite) display math correctly, if it will run properly with a 1000-page book with math all around?
2. I do have the same question as the first one quoted above, but would like an updated answer: should I be asking a new one or launching a bounty for the old one? Eitherway, the answer will be outdated in few months.
3. Instead of MSE, should I be asking such questions here in Meta.MSE?
4. Do we have a policy about questions/answers which will be/is outdated/redundant now?

Comment: I think the general dictum for questions about math-related software should apply pretty well here:  is the issue more of a support topic or of a mathematical topic?  I'm reluctant to draw a broad conclusion about device-related Questions, because there seems no guarantee of a nexus with mathematical reasoning but it cannot be excluded.

Comment: 1. It's a bit close to a support request, but I'd give it a bit more leeway than usual - the official support may not be as accurate as what actual people are experiencing (but this is *really* borderline). 2. It should be a new question. 3. No, this would be far off-topic for MSE.